# How can I change the format of this dates in R

Tags: r

I have this dates in R:

```
> head(mydates)

[1] "2007-01-01" "2007-01-02" "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08"
> class(mydates)

[1] "Date"
```

And I want to change it into this format

```
> head(targetdates)

[1] "2007-01-01 GMT" "2007-01-02 GMT" "2007-01-03 GMT" "2007-01-04 GMT"
[5] "2007-01-05 GMT" "2007-01-08 GMT"
> class(targetdates)

[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

How can I do this (in R)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `as.POSIXct`

```
mydates
## [1] "2007-01-01" "2007-01-02" "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08"

class(mydates)
## [1] "Date"

Sys.setenv(TZ = "GMT") #necessary of you want dates to be printed in GMT
as.POSIXct(mydates)
## [1] "2007-01-01 GMT" "2007-01-02 GMT" "2007-01-03 GMT" "2007-01-04 GMT" "2007-01-05 GMT" "2007-01-08 GMT"
```

Also read `?POSIXct`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as.POSIXlt` :

```
R> as.POSIXlt(mydates, tz="GMT")
[1] "2007-01-01 UTC" "2007-01-02 UTC" "2007-01-03 UTC" "2007-01-04 UTC"
[5] "2007-01-05 UTC" "2007-01-08 UTC"
```

Comment: OP is looking for `POSIXct`.

Answer (score 0):

With the `lubridate`package you can "force" the date to GMT by means of the `force_tz` function:

```
library(lubridate)

mydate <- as.Date("2007-01-01")
class(mydate)
#[1] "Date"

mydate1 <- as.POSIXlt(mydate) # or use as.POSIXct but you get a datetime format then.
mydate1
#[1] "2007-01-01 UTC"

mydate2 <- force_tz(mydate1, tzone = "GMT")
mydate2
#[1] "2007-01-01 GMT"

class(mydate2)
#[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
> as.POSIXct(format(mydates), tz = "GMT")
[1] "2007-01-01 GMT" "2007-01-02 GMT" "2007-01-03 GMT" "2007-01-04 GMT"
[5] "2007-01-05 GMT" "2007-01-08 GMT"
```

(There is some question of why you would want to do this and not just stick with `"Date"` class if your data is daily.)